Flask Nginx docker web page not responding - windows
Everything runs fine, the flask port 5000 works, but Nginx port web page not responding.
Please help and thank you.
Here are my code, docker file, nginx.conf, .py:
[[[[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/DaL2USe4.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/WxePtfkw.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/8rFgAXTK.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/BO1CmnQz.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/gYVc7cSI.jpg)
Finding proper way of using flask and Nginx.

one of the image has an incorrect name of .conf, should be nginx.conf.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to replace all of the image links with the actual code and error messages, in plain text?

Thanks for the feedback, my problem is solved, I will do that for future posts.

Solved by changing the port to 8080 instead of 80.

Please be more specific, even if you solved the issue by yourself, someone might have the need of receive more information on how to solve this.

On Windows, binding to lower port numbers (below 1024, such as 80) requires administrative privileges, higher ports like 8080 don't have these restrictions.
